# Java spring DTO -> Entity perfomance improvement

Tags: java, spring

I have a super large JSON coming in from a REST service. 50-100 objects all of them having additional # nr of sub objects. The processing of it is straight forward.

Find existing object in the database or create new. Use setters to add values. Save object. And with subObjects there is the additional step to add it to the parent entity.

It is taking more than 60 seconds to process it. Is there a way to improve the speed of it?

Example of what the code looks like:

```
for (Parent parent: parentInput.getParents()) {
        ParentEntity parentEntity =
            initParentEntity(parent.getParentRefNr());
        parentEntity .setCpvCode(parent.getCpvCode());
        parentEntity .setCpvName(parent.getCpvName());
       ....
        parentMChildRepository.deleteByParent(parentEntity.getId());

        for (ChildInput childInput: parent.getChildInputList()) {

            ChildEntity childEntity = childRepository.findByErhrId(childInput
                .getChildERHRId());
            if (childEntity == null) {
                childEntity = new ChildEntity ();
            }
            childEntity .setErhrId(childInput
                .getChildERHRId());
            childEntity .setFirstName(childInput.getFirstName());
            childEntity .setLastName(childInput.getLastName());
            childEntity .setIdentityCode(childInput.getIdentityCode());
           ....

            childEntity = childRepository.save(childEntity );

            parentEntity
                .addChildEntity(childEntity);
        }
        parentRepository.save(parentEntity);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that 60s+ could possibly come from hundreds (or even thousands) of such objects and operations you performing on them. It must be something else - GC pressure, db connectivity issues, http throttling of some kind which slows things down. I would recommend attaching any profiler of your choice (yourkit, visualvm) to see where bottleneck is. I would put my money on IO but it might be cpu as well.

Comment: check with some profiler what it takes more time, later it is easier. Then you will know if It is the communication of this huge JSON, the communication with DB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest optimisation would be following: accumulate children to some collection and save them all in bulk (in one operation). You would instantly gain performance increase because of reduced db operations.

Comment: Do i need to save the childEntities separately? the addChildEntity method creates the ParentMChildEntity. Gives itthe parent and the child entity + few more values, and then adds to a Set parentMChildEntities that is mapped with OneToMany.